# How to test if object has a type odict_values in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, ordereddictionary

On a project I have a generic function, which can take different data types as input data. While migrating project to Python 3 I have an issue with `odict_values`. I need to convert those to list, unfortunately, not all data types should be converted. So I decided to do something like this:

```
if isinstance(data, odict_values):
    data = list(data)
```

But I get an error - undefined variable odict_values. I don't understand what should I provide as a second argument for isinstance. I can clearly see `<class 'odict_values'>` if I use `type(data)`. The best solution I came up so far is to use:

`str(type(data)) == "<class 'odict_values'>"`

but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `odict_values` type is not accessible in the built-in types, nor in the `collections` module.

That means you have to define it yourself:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
odict_values = type(OrderedDict().values())
```

You can (and probably should) use a more descriptive name for this type than `odict_values`.

However you can then you can use this type as second argument for `isinstance` checks:

```
isinstance({1: 1}.values(), odict_values)                   # False
isinstance(OrderedDict([(1, 1)]).values(), odict_values)    # True
```

---

If you want a more general test if it's a view on the values of a mapping (like `dict` and `OrderedDict`), then you could use the abstract base class [`ValuesView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ValuesView):

```
from collections.abc import ValuesView

isinstance({1: 1}.values(), ValuesView)                   # True
isinstance(OrderedDict([(1, 1)]).values(), ValuesView)    # True
```